On the expression $\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1}$, where $\zeta_n$ is an $n$-th root of unity.
Let $\mathbb F_p$ be a finite field with $p$ elements, where $p$ is an odd prime. In addition, suppose that $\zeta_n$ is an $n$-th root of unity in some extension $\mathbb K$ of $\mathbb F_p$ such that $\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1}\in\mathbb F_p$. What can be said on $p$ and $n$?
Clearly, if $\zeta_n\in\mathbb F_p$, then $\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1}\in\mathbb F_p$, but it is possible that $\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1}\in\mathbb F_p$ for $\zeta_n\notin\mathbb F_p$. For example, if $n=3$ and $\sqrt{-3}\notin F_p$, then $\zeta_3+\zeta_3^{-1}=-1\in\mathbb F_p$.

Surely $\zeta\in\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ and so $n|p^2-1$?

Thanks, but why $\zeta\in\mathbb F_{p^2}$?

$\zeta$ is a root of $X^2-(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})X+1\in\mathbb{F}_p[X]$.

For $c:=\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1}$ you have $$\zeta_n^2-c\zeta_n+1=0$$ so if $c\in\Bbb{F}p$ then $\zeta_n\in\Bbb{F}{p^2}$.

Thanks. Does $n\mid p^2-2$ is suffices for $c\in \mathbb F_p$ ?

Maybe you ought to spend a bit of time thinking about the problem now that you've had pointers.

Assuming $n\mid p^2-1$. What do you know about Galois conjugates of $\zeta_n$? Could it happen that $\zeta_n^{-1}$ is among them?
